# Incorrect logging message after override $log

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-log, angularjs-decorator

I'm trying to decorate the angular's `$log` factory to put the `timestamp` of the message in the log.

It works pretty well until now, except for this behavior:

When I log with default configuration of angular, I receive:

> message for Object {name: "bryan", message: "was here"} third argument

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/crVdJf68PGpaGbsxzHz3?p=preview)

After creating the decorator, the logs became this:

> ["message for", Object, "third argument"]

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tNDA0vWAJrfOuIvSC1lr?p=preview) - The code is here

So, the Object was not expanded to the console, and I need to click at the message to see the full object.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Or know a better way to do this and put the timestamp in the beginning of the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand the `argument` array into a list of arguments for `warn()`. You can achieve it with `apply()`. It is just a JavaScript trick.

```
warn: function () {
    //create a new args. You can't modify arguments since it is controlled by AngularJS
    var args = [new Date()];
    angular.forEach(arguments, function (i) {
        args.push(i);
    })
    $delegate.warn.apply(null, args);
}
```

`$delegate.warn.apply(null, args);` evaluates as `$delegate.warn(args[0], args[1], ...);`.